# How do I remove/delete a total added to an SSRS group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I cannot believe that I am asking this question.  It seems like it should be so simple. I have already spent a bunch of time online looking for the answer.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 to develop an SSRS report.

All I need to do is remove a total row from a tablix.  Essentially I want to reverse what this guidance from MSDN shows on [how to add a total row](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd239342.aspx).  I can remove the content from the row easily enough, but now I have a empty row.  I don't want an empty row. (Notice the blank row to the right of the CR group label.)

[image: my blank total row]

Here's how I created the total row.
[image: how i added the total row]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so this was fairly simple.  Must have been a brain cramp !  Basically in design view on the report, you just need to select the cells that were added by the Add Total (which is ***NOT*** the entire row) and then right click and choose Delete Rows